# Method does not exist or incorrect signature...?

Tags: apex, deployment, compile-error, deployment-error

I'm trying to deploy/validate a class but getting this error, even though the class is working in the sandbox.

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature void buildHTTPRequest(String,String,String,String) 
from the type HTTPRequestBuilder
```

It's coming from this class :

```
public with sharing class Http_Utility_Pardot {
    

    public static String login(Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt pardotTrackingConfig) {
        
        String requestBody = 'email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.UserName__c, Constants.UTF_8)
                                + '&password=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.Passward__c, Constants.UTF_8)
                                + '&user_key=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.User_Key__c, Constants.UTF_8);

        
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:APEX_Pardot_Credential/account/version/4/do/read');        
        request.setHeader('Pardot-Business-Unit-Id', '0Uv2J000000CaWgX13');
        
        request.setMethod('POST');
        
        HttpResponse response = HTTPService.send(request);
        
        return HTTPResponseParser.parseLoginResponse(response);
        
    }

    public static String pardotCreateProspect(Set<Id> contactIds) {
        

        List<Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt> pardotTrackingConfigs = [SELECT Id, Login_URL__c, UserName__c, Passward__c, User_Key__c,
                                                                            Email_Tracking_URL__c, Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c, Batch_Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c
                                                                            FROM Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = 'Pardot_Tracking_Data'];
        
        if(pardotTrackingConfigs.size() == 0)
            return System.Label.Pardot_Error_PTC_Not_Defined;
        
        
        String apiKey = login(pardotTrackingConfigs[0]);
        if(contactIds.size() == 0)
            return System.Label.Pardot_Error_Contact_Id_Missing;
            
        // Querying the particular Contact details for the creation of Prospect record  
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id =: contactIds];
        if(contacts.size() == 0)
            return System.Label.Pardot_Error_Invalid_Contact;

            String endpoint;
            String requestBody;            

            Map<String, String> headerParameters= new Map<String, String>{'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id' => '0Uv2J000000CaWgX13'};
            
           if(contacts.size() == 1){  
                Contact contactRecord = contacts[0];  

            endpoint = 'callout:APEX_Pardot_Credential/prospect/version/4/do/create/email/' + contactRecord.Email;
            requestBody = 'first_name=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.FirstName,Constants.UTF_8)
                                    + '&last_name=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.LastName,Constants.UTF_8)
                                    + '&email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.Email,Constants.UTF_8);
                                    //+ '&crm_owner_fid=' + contactRecord.OwnerId;

        } else {
        
            endpoint = pardotTrackingConfigs[0].Batch_Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c;
            requestBody = '';
            for(Contact contactRecord:contacts){
                                                        
                requestBody = requestBody +'{"email":"' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.Email,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                          + '","first_name":"'+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.FirstName,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                          + '","last_name":"'+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.LastName,Constants.UTF_8)                                           + '",},';

                }
                
                requestBody = 'prospects={"prospects":['+ requestBody.removeEnd(',')+']}';
        }       
        
        **HttpRequest request= HTTPRequestBuilder.buildHTTPRequest(endpoint, Constants.POST,
                                                                        Constants.APPLICATIONX_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED,
                                                                        requestBody);
        request.setHeader('Pardot-Business-Unit-Id', '0Uv2J000000CaWgX13');**
        
        HttpResponse response = HTTPService.send(request);
        return HTTPResponseParser.parseCreateRecordResponse(response);
    }
}
```

And this is the class it is referencing, which has that buildHTTPRequest method :

```
public class HTTPRequestBuilder {    public static HttpRequest createSky(String endPoint, String requestBody){


        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        request.setBody(requestBody);
    system.debug(request);
        return request;
    }
    
    public static HttpRequest buildHTTPRequest(String endPoint, String methodType, String contentType, 
                                            Map<String, String> headerParameters, String requestBody) {

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        request.setMethod(methodType);
        request.setHeader('content-type', contentType);

        if(headerParameters != null) {
            for(String headerKey: headerParameters.keySet()) {
                
                request.setHeader(headerKey, headerParameters.get(headerKey));
            }
        }
        request.setBody(requestBody);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what is causing this ? Thank you.

Comment: Seems pretty clear. You're trying to call `buildHTTPRequest(String, String, String, String)` but the signature your `HTTPRequestBuilder` has is `buildHTTPRequest(String, String, String, Map<String, String>, String)`. Your call is missing the 4th parameter (`Map<String, String>`). Either your usage is wrong or you've made an update to `HTTPRequestBuilder` that needs to be deployed as well.

Comment: @DerekF - thank you so much. I guess I'm going to have to write a whole test class for this ? I'm looking through the whole library and there isn't one (and this is code that is already deployed). Do you know of any examples I could reference to see fitting test classes for this ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing all the parameters that are required to the buildHTTPRequest() method. You are not including the headerParameters. That's why you get the compilation error.

Comment: So do I have to write a whole test class for HTTPRequestBuilder ? Can you give me an example of something I could use to get me started on it ? Thanks !

Comment: In case there is no class covering it, yes, you should write a test class for that class but I don't see the relation between the initial question and this one. About how to test a class that performs an external callout, you can check out the following Trailhead Unit which explains exactly what you need https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts